# Laravel PHPunit Setup data is null in dataprovider

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have nothing write into testcase, it is just empty like

```
public function testData() {
}
public function dataProvider() {
   dd($this->id)
}
```

But I have written query into setup

```
 /*
 * create the object against which we will test
 */
protected function setUp() :void
{
    parent::setup();
    
    $this->id = Event::inRandomOrder()->select('id')->whereNotNull('logo')->first();
    dd($this->id);    
}
```

But this is not calling and getting below in output

```
No test executed
```

command I am trying is

```
php artisan test --filter <classname>
```

my PHPUnit is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Please don't create duplicate posts. The database of Laravel the way its accessed has not been made for dataprovers in phpunit. This does not change only re-posting about the same issue. Follow the guides of the Laravel documentation on how to test models and db with phpunit.

Answer (score 1):

Dataproviders need to return something that is passed into the test.

They are resolved before setup or your test is run. Even before the laravel application is set up.

If you want to run something from the dataprovider, put it in a callback. Keep in mind, you won't be able modify attributes of the class in the dataprovider with `$this->...`.

```php
/**
 * @dataProvider data
 */
public function testData($callback)
{
   $value = $callback(); //Value will be the return value of the callback.
   dd($value);
   // Do rest of test
}

public function data()
{
   return [
      'it can run a callback' => [
         function() {
            // Do stuff here inside the test
            return 'something';

         }
      ]
   ];
}
```

This approach is really good for when you need access to factories, etc, in the dataprovider, but the application has not been set up yet when the dataprovider is run.

This blog is a really good source for the different ways of using dataproviders in laravel.
https://tighten.co/blog/tidying-up-your-phpunit-tests-with-data-providers/

When running tests, `--filter` is for the method name in the test class.

Try

```
php artisan test <path to classname> --filter testData
```

Comment: tried but still I can't get setup() data in dataprovider

Comment: Dataproviders are run before setup. You could get the dataprovider to return a callback which you then run in your test.

Comment: how to do that?